# Actualizar datos de graficos - Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Quiero actualizar los datos del gráfico con nuevos valores aleatorios cuando presione el botón alterar.

Adjunte el código de un programa simple de prueba, pero la idea es implementarlo en un programa con varios graficos

Se que una forma de hacerlo sería redibujar el gráfico, pero tengo entendido que es un proceso lento y puede consumir mucha memoria si tengo varias figuras.

Hay alguna otra manera de hacerlo?

```
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import seaborn as sb
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

root = tk.Tk()
root.minsize(width = 350, height = 500)

def alterar():
    for i in range(0, len(dataframe.columns)):
        for j in range(0, len(dataframe.index)):
            dataframe.loc[j, i] = np.random.randint(0, 50)

dataframe = pd.DataFrame(columns = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], index = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

for i in range(0, len(dataframe.columns)):
    for j in range(0, len(dataframe.index)):
        dataframe.loc[j, i] = np.random.randint(0, 50)

figura, eje = plt.subplots(figsize = (3, 4), dpi = 100)
sb.heatmap(dataframe, ax = eje)

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figura, root)
canvas.get_tk_widget().place(x = 10, y = 10)

boton = tk.Button(root, text = "Alterar", command = alterar)
boton.place(x = 10, y = 450)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El código necesita un par de cambios para funcionar:

- el `heatmap` no acepta un dataframe, hay que convertirlo a un numpy array
- dentro `alterar` hay que crear otra vez el heatmap; para no repetir código, la primera vez se puede dibujar llamando `alterar()` explícitamente
- `figura.canvas.draw()` muestra el cambio en la pantalla
- el `heatmap` de seaborn no solo dibuja un heatmap pero también añade un colorbar; para evitar que añade un colorbar nuevo cada vez, hay que darle un eje a proposito
- este eje se puede crear al mismo tiempo que el eje principal con `subplots`; por defecto `subplots` hace las áreas iguales; el parametro `width_ratios` ayuda para tener más espacio para el eje principal

El código cambiado:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

root = tk.Tk()
root.minsize(width=350, height=500)

def alterar():
    for i in range(0, len(dataframe.columns)):
        for j in range(0, len(dataframe.index)):
            dataframe.loc[j, i] = np.random.randint(0, 50)
    sns.heatmap(np.array(dataframe, dtype=float), ax=eje, cbar_ax=eje_cbar)
    figura.canvas.draw()

dataframe = pd.DataFrame(columns=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], index=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

figura, (eje, eje_cbar) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(3, 4), dpi=100,
                                       gridspec_kw={'width_ratios': [10, 1]})

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figura, root)
canvas.get_tk_widget().place(x=10, y=10)

boton = tk.Button(root, text="Alterar", command=alterar)
boton.place(x=10, y=450)

alterar()
root.mainloop()
```

PD: Un dataframe de pandas no es muy adecuado para guardar una matriz. Mejor emplear numpy directamente, especialmente para matrices grandes.

La matriz del ejemplo se puede crear con una sola línea:

```
matriz = np.random.randint(0, 50, size=(6,6))
```

También es costumbre de importar las librarías siempre con las mismas abreviaciones. Eso ayuda a otra gente entender el código. Para seaborn la abrevación habitual es `sns`. (El motivo viene de [una serie de televisión](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41499857/seaborn-why-import-as-sns/44484758)).

Comment: Buena respuesta, no sabía que la abreviación venía de una serie de tv, la verdad es que siempre me pareció raro...  :)